# Add existing external library to new project in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I want to use "android-spatialite-2.0.0" library in my new project(The image is attached). Can anyone help me?

[image: sample image]

Answer (score 2):

As i see your screenshot. You can not just add compiled library to your project.

You can do two things

1. Either add `compile 'com.github.sevar83:android-spatialite:2.0.0'` to build.gradle.
2. Or download this projects zip and add as a module.

By the way 1st one is recommended for further upgrades.

Answer (score 0):

Paste your `.jar` file into `libs` folder of your project.
 [image: Check below image]

After adding right click on jar file and click on Add As Library option. 
[image]

Comment: I try this solution but I get the following error: "*.so" file not found